# GenerateTableFetch drops flowfile on no data for query

Tags: apache-nifi, hortonworks-data-platform, hortonworks-dataflow

I am using using `GenerateTableFetch` with incoming flow files containing `table_name` to import data. And I have put `Additional WHERE clause` to handle incremental updates using `updated_at` column of the table manually.

Issue is when there is no data to import for the constructed query, it simply drops the flow file. It should have a separate relationship other than success and failure for this case so that I can handle on my own if something has to be done for such cases.

Currently, at the start of the workflow, I am using `Wait` on number of tables I have put into flow and tracking when they are done to increment the done count using `Notify`. But for the tables which get's dropped in `GenerateTableFetch`, it just keeps on waiting.

Any way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

This would indeed be a good improvement to add to GenerateTableFetch, perhaps an optional property to "Output Empty FlowFile on Zero Results" or something. I have written [NIFI-5604](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-5604) to cover this improvement. Combining this with NIFI-5601, you could do routing downstream (if fragment.count = 0 for example).

Comment: Yes. A property or a separate relationship like `no-result` would be great to handle this. Related to NIFI-5601, I got working version using `MergeContent` for now. But these are some of the major blockers for our ingestion pipeline. :(